# Comparing Two Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare two Pandas DataFrames based on the dtypes of the columns. These are the scenarios:

1. If the dtype is 'object' each data entry in the first df needs to match exactly to the corresponding entry in the second df
2. If the dtype is 'float' or 'int' they need to be close to one another

here is what I have so far:

```
for column in data_1.columns:
if df_1[column].dtypes == 'float' or  df_1[column].dtypes == 'int':
    comparison[column] = np.isclose(df_1[column], df_2[column])
else:
    comparison[column] = df_1[column].where(df_1[column].values == df_2[column].values).notna()
```

However, in my comparison dataframe, I get quite a few false positives, i.e where the values in both columns are the same, I have 'False' in my comparison dataframe.
To test this, I printed out some of the subtraction of data points that were showing as false, and the result was 0, which is expected:

```
print(np.isclose(df_1[df_1['id']=='72']['cad'], df_2[df_2['id']=='72']['cad'])) 
print(df_1[df_1['id']=='72']['cad'] - df_2[df_2['id']=='72']['cad'])
```

Can anyone help me understand where I am screwing this up?

**Edit:**
As I could not share the data I was working with, I put together a mini example that included all steps that I was performing and got the expected result:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a', ''], ['b', '2.0'], ['c', '3.01']]),columns=['id', 'value'])
df1['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['value'], errors='coerce')

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a', ''], ['b', '2.0'], ['c', '3.0']]),columns=['id', 'value'])
df2['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df2['value'], errors='coerce')


comparison = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'value'])
for column in df1.columns:
    if df1[column].dtypes == 'float' or  df1[column].dtypes == 'int':
        comparison[column] = np.isclose(df1[column], df2[column], equal_nan=True, atol=0.01, rtol=0.01)
    else:
        comparison[column] = df1[column].where(df1[column].values == df2[column].values).notna()
print(comparison.head())
```

Upon more investigation, I found that this was caused by missing id's in the original data sets that I was sorting by.

Comment: Please share some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Maybe you can use [Pandas testing module to compare two dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have it working for a simple toy example, hopefully this works for you as well. I have set the `atol` to 0.1 so that the 3rd element of b should be close enough (True) and the 2nd element should be too far away (False)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('abcd'), 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('ab3d'), 'b': [1, 20.3, 3.05, 4]})
comparison = pd.DataFrame()

for col in df1.columns: 
    if df1[col].dtypes in ["int", "float"]:
        comparison[col] = np.isclose(df1[col], df2[col], atol=0.1)
   else: 
        comparison[col] = df1[col] == df2[col]
```

```
comparison 
       a      b
0   True   True
1   True  False
2  False   True
3   True   True
```